# How to get two columns using linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of Group which have warning and Categories.

So based on the type I want to Filter the group to show only the category and warning which has
the type "Drug to Drug Interaction" value alone.

I wrote two linq query but failed to get both category and warnings

Linq 1 :

```
var warnings_latest = groups.SelectMany(g => g.Warnings).Where(w => w.Type == "Drug to Drug Interaction");
```

In the above case I can able to filter warnings alone but I can't able to get the categories

Linq 2 :

```
var warnings = groups.SelectMany(g => g.Warnings , (parent,child) => new { parent.Category, child.Type,child.Description,child.Target }).Where(w => w.Type == "Drug to Drug Interaction");
```

In the above case I can select the categories as a whole but with respect to warnings I can't able to access the whole warnings. I don't know how to combine child properties into warnings class

Group.cs

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Emis.Medication.UI.Warnings
{
    partial class DataGridView
    {
        private partial class Group
        {
            [GeneratedCode("Emis.Weaving", null)]
            public Group(
                Category category,
                ReadOnlyCollection<Common.Warnings.Mkb.Warning> warnings)
            {
                _category = category;
                _warnings = warnings;
            }

            private readonly Category _category;
            private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Common.Warnings.Mkb.Warning> _warnings;

            public Category Category
            {
                get { return _category; }
            }

            public ReadOnlyCollection<Common.Warnings.Mkb.Warning> Warnings
            {
                get { return _warnings; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Warnings.cs :

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace Emis.Medication.Common.Warnings.Mkb
{
    internal partial class Warning
    {
        [GeneratedCode("Emis.Weaving", null)]
        public Warning(
            String description,
            String target,
            String type)
        {
            _description = description;
            _target = target;
            _type = type;
        }

        private readonly String _description;
        private readonly String _target;
        private readonly String _type;

        public String Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
        }

        public String Target
        {
            get { return _target; }
        }

        public String Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
        }
    }
}
```

Category.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emis.Collections.Generic;
using Emis.Common.FrameworkExtensionMethods;

namespace Emis.Medication.UI.Warnings
{
    partial class DataGridView
    {
        private abstract partial class Category
        {


            public abstract Color Background { get; }
            public abstract Color Border { get; }
            public abstract Color Foreground { get; }
            public abstract Image Icon { get; }
            public abstract Boolean IsOverrideRequired { get; }
            public abstract Int32 Order { get; }
            public abstract String Title { get; }

            protected virtual IDataGridViewRowFactory DataGridViewRowFactory
            {
                get { return new DataGridViewRowFactory(); }
            }

    }
}
```

Expected :

A linq query which filters using the warning type and provide both category and warnings in the select list.

**EDITED :**

with respect to the comments I have changed my linq to

```
var data =  groups.SelectMany(g => g.Warnings.Select(w => new  { g.Category, Warnings = w })).ToList().Where(x => x.Warnings.Type == "Drug to Drug Interaction").ToReadOnlyCollection();
```

The above query helped me to have the desired result since we have built a group I tried to assign it like below

```
        ReadOnlyCollection<Group> data =  groups.SelectMany(g => g.Warnings.Select(w => new  { g.Category, Warnings = w })).ToList().Where(x => x.Warnings.Type == "Drug to Drug Interaction").ToReadOnlyCollection();
```

But facing the below issue

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<<anonymous type: Emis.Medication.UI.Warnings.DataGridView.Category Category, Emis.Medication.Common.Warnings.Mkb.Warning Warnings>>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<Emis.Medication.UI.Warnings.DataGridView.Group>'
```

Comment: Use something like this : groups.SelectMany(g => g.Warnings.SelectMany(w => g.Categories.Select(c => new {warnings = w, categories = c})));

Comment: @jdweng In the Categories.Select I'm getting the error that "Datagridview.Category" doesn't contain a definition for select and no accessible extension method.

Comment: I thought categories was a group.  Try : groups.SelectMany(g => g.Warnings.Select(w => new {warnings = w, categories = g.category})).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng I have updated the question and let me know your idea on why I'm facing the casting issue.

Comment: @jdweng I resolved the issue. Thanks for your help. If you want please provide it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the groups that have a minimum of one warning with type "Drug to Drug Interaction", simply do

```
var result = groups.Where(g => g.Warnings.Any(warning => warning.Type == "Drug to Drug Interaction"));
```

Or query syntax

```
var res = (from g in groups
          where g.Warnings.Any(warning => warning.Type == "Drug to Drug Interaction")
          select g).ToList();
```

No need to SelectMany()

Comment: my issue a group will have one category and multiple warnings. Here I want to filter the warnings which has only type "Drug to Drug Interaction alone". Your case is  assuming if i have two or more groups. so with ur query I'm getting all the warnings.

Comment: If you want to assign the selected data to a variable of type ReadOnlyCollection<Group>, then it has to be Groups you select? Are you sure you actually know what you want?